# filter tibble with group_by ALL records in vector (without multiple ANY statements)

Tags: r, filter, group-by, slice

I was just wondering whether it is possible to select (filter) the whole group in a dataframe/tibble based on a vector as input.

This is my example (small) dataset:

```
# load packages
require(tidyverse)

# make example data
data1 <- tibble(a = "groep", b = c(1,2,3)) 
data2 <- tibble( a = "groep2", b = c(1,2))
data3 <- tibble( a = "groep3", b = c(1,2,3,4))
data4 <- tibble( a = "groep4", b = c(2,3,5))

#combine example data
example <- bind_rows(data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

Now I would like to extract the groups that contains the numbers 1,2 and 3. A.k.a. **data1** and **data3**.
I would like to do this with a `group_by` function.

I could do this:

```
example %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(any(b ==1) & any(b==2) & any(b==3)) %>% ungroup
```

I am satisfied with the output, though I wonder whether there is a less cumbersome method?
These are just 3 `any`'s in this block of code. But what if there

```
vec <- c(1,2,3)
```

Is it possible to generate the same output using this vector **"vec"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%in%` with `all`

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   filter(all(vec %in% b)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  a          b
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 groep      1
2 groep      2
3 groep      3
4 groep3     1
5 groep3     2
6 groep3     3
7 groep3     4
```

Comment: @T.BruceLee that would return TRUE for all a groups because `vec` and `c(1, 2, 3)` are the same.  instead you want to compare with the column values from 'b'

Comment: I deleted my comment, because I made a typo, so my comment wasn't helpful.

This is what I meant:
I tried "all( )" before, but as it turns out " all(vec %in% b)" is not the same as "all(b %in% vec)"  :)